# Topological property of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: functions, continuity

This question is how to prove the following statement:

$$\forall \text{continuous }f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2(\exists \alpha,\beta>0 (\forall a\in(0,\alpha](\forall b\in(0,\beta](f[[0,a]\times[0,b]]\text{ is simply connected}))))$$

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with the [Hawaiian earring](http://oliversullivanhorn@gmail.com) you may be able to perceive a counterexample, which I'll describe briefly.

Let $C_n$ be the circle of radius $1/2^n$ in the right half-plane tangent to the $y$-axis at $(0,0)$. Let $C = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} C_n$; this is a version of the Hawaiian earring. One can construct a continuous path $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ with image $C$, such that the restricted path $\gamma \mid [2^{-k},2^{-k+1}]$ goes once around the circle $C_k$ at constant speed. Thus, the restriction to $[0,2^{-k}]$ contains infinitely many distinct circles $C_{k+1},C_{k+2},\ldots$ and evidently has non-simply connected image.

Now define $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\gamma(x^2+y^2) &\quad\text{if $x^2+y^2 \le 1$} \\
\gamma(1) &\quad\text{if $x^2 + y^2 \ge 1$}
\end{cases}
$$